# How to encrypt RSA in lua?

Tags: encryption, lua, rsa

I want to convert rsa in Lua using the following parameters. I need to send a 6-digit code as RSA encrypted to perform a payment transaction. I couldn't do this in Lua. Can you share a code sample?

```
Exponent=AQAB
Modulus=1EYDa43a8My50miTEK2miAzw8Rl/1HqG+XT0LuBdoKtZLdKe35xAOlr0DTk/Bp6...
```

I don't want to share the full public key for security reasons.

---

The code sample I developed is as follows.

```
prm_inData = "123456";
function Encryption(prm_inData)
    local outData1 = ""
    if(prm_inData ~= nil) then
        local IVVee = ""
        local len = ""
        local len2 = ""

        IVVee = AQAB;
        len = string.len(prm_inData)

        rsa = vpos.crypt.RSA()
        if(rsa ~= nil) then
            enc= rsa:getPublicKey("1EYDa43a8My50miTEK2miAzw...");
            outData1 = rsa:encrypt(prm_inData, IVVee)
        end
        len2 = string.len(outData1)
        return outData1
    end
end
```

The code sample I developed is as follows. When I encrypt it returns 1281. I think I did the operation wrong. Where am I doing wrong? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `I need to send a 6-digit code as RSA encrypted` - RSA is unable to encrypt such short messages.  The minimal message size is the size of modulus.  You would have to pad your message with random bits.  Does receiving side expect this?

Comment: A quick google of *Lua rsa code* will get you much further along. In particular there are some Github projects that might help.